# How can I prevent phone's screen from turning off while calling on Android pie (9) with ADB (or without, if possible)

Tags: android, adb, proximity, android-9.0-pie

I want to disable proximity sensor. My proximity sensor blinks during call and I don't want it to, so by disabling it, I hope this won't occur.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: There were some guides involving changing call settings but they don't work with android pie but I have heard it can be done using adb tools